# Регулярное выражение для всех видов ссылок

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Можете посоветовать регулярное выражение для url для таких ссылок

```
https://www.google.ru/
http://www.google.ru/
www.google.ru
google.ru
```

Comment: Вот: http://stackoverflow.com/a/190405/276994

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужны все ссылки, а не только google то:

```
#^(?:(?:http(?:s)?)://)?(?:www\.)?[^/]+\.[^/]+(?:/)?#
```

Только регулярное выражение:

```
#^(?:(?:http(?:s)?)://)?(?:www\.)?google\.ru(?:/)?#
```

Пример кода:

```
function checkGoogle($url) {
    $pattern = '#^(?:(?:http(?:s)?)://)?(?:www\.)?google\.ru(?:/)?#';
    return (bool)preg_match($pattern, $url);
}
$test = array(
    'https://www.google.ru/',
    'http://www.google.ru/',
    'www.google.ru',
    'google.ru',
    'notgoogle.ru'
);
foreach ($test as $testcase){
    var_dump(checkGoogle($testcase));
}
unset($testcase);
//True True True True False
```

Можно обойтись и без регулярок, если нужны только такие ссылки. Функция поменяется:

```
function checkGoogle($url) {
$google_urls = array(
    'https://www.google.ru/',
    'http://www.google.ru/',
    'www.google.ru',
    'google.ru'
);
return in_array($url, $google_urls);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа:

```
#.+:\/\/(.+\..+\..{2,3})\/#
```

Для

```
https://www.google.ru/
```

Найдёт

```
www.google.ru
```

**UPD** немного подправил

Comment: Не найдет www.google.ru и google.ru из предложенного списка... Ваше регулярное выражение выбирает только те ссылки, у которых указан хост и слеш на конце. Более того, ограничив доменную зону 2-3 символами, вы выкинули из выборки url, заканчивающиеся на .info, .name, .asia и так далее.